# Get highscore from 100+ tables to show in summary

Tags: mysql, sql

I have +100 games on my website. Each game has it's own highscore table. The structure of the table is always the same (same columns etc.).

On a central page, as a summary, I would like to show the highscores a user has for all the games.

What would be the most efficient way to do this? I was thinking about just doing a SELECT query 100+ times (one for each table), but that doesn't sound very performance friendly:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE user_id=? AND something_else=?");
$stmt->bind_param('is', $user_id, $something_else);
```

Tips?

Comment: Fix your broken schema. :-(

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way is to fix your data model.  Having 100+ tables with the same structure is a sign of a very poor design.

With one table -- and an additional column for the game -- you would simply do:

```
select ahs.*
from all_high_scores ahs
where ahs.use_id = ?;
```

Without that, you are stuck.  MySQL is not great about optimizing queries, so I don't think this will work:

```
create view v_all_high_scores as
    select * from high_scores_01 union all
    select * from high_scores_02 union all
    select * from high_scores_03 union all
    . . .;

select *
from v_all_high_scores ahs
where user_id = ?
```

You might get lucky -- many databases will push the condition to the individual tables.  And MySQL might do that in its current version.

Another approach is a brute force approach, with a zillion parameters:

```
select * from high_scores_1 where user_id = ? union all
select * from high_scores_2 where user_id = ? union all
select * from high_scores_3 where user_id = ? union all
. . .;
```

However, you should fix the data model, so you can write this efficiently in one query.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I used to have all the highscores in one table as you mention, with an additional game column, but the problem with that approach was that the table became really big. Even with composite indexes, query's became very slow, certainly because I needed to do percentile calculations etc. There were also 5 extra WHERE clauses next to the game filtering. The combination of this all made it too slow to fetch data. We thought about caching more complex calculations like the percentiles but even then it was kinda slow (as in 5-20 seconds wait to get the data).

Comment: @binoculars That's where indexing and then range partitioning comes in. Go back to that model.

Comment: Indexing didn't made it fast enough. I'll look into partitioning, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to be able to access the stats for all games from either one table, or a similar construct.

Have you considered using partitioned tables? This will allow the table to be split into many sub tables (one for each game) - based on a partitioning property (in this case the game ID). However, within SQL, it appears as one table, not 100 sub tables.

When you query based on a game ID say, the query will be directed to the one sub table that holds data for that game. This way, it will allow you to retain the optimisation you had by holding the game data in multiple tables, as before.

The same will happen, when you perform an insert - the new row will be stored in the relevant sub table.

However, if you want to select data across multiple sub-tables, then you can query the partitioned table without specifying the partitioning value, and it will query all sub tables, and act as if it is returning data from one table.

The following blog explains more:

https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/07/27/what-is-mysql-partitioning/#:~:targetText=Partitioning%20is%20a%20way%20in,find%20a%20natural%20partition%20key.

Comment: Sounds interesting. I'll look into using partitioned tables.